# Windows PXE Boot freezes in KVM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, pxe-boot, qemu, wds, sysprep

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 running WDS/DHCP Service and an Ubuntu Server 16.04.4 as a qemu/kvm host where is running a Windows 7 vm as an image to capture for WDS (syspreped).

Now when i want to PXE boot the Win7 vm, i get into Windows Boot Manager, but when i choose the operationg system i get a black screen after the image was loaded. I also pressed F8 for advanced options and choosed "Safe Mode with Command Promt". Then it hangs at "Loaded: \WINDOWS\system32\drivers\disk.sys".

I created a new vm with a blank HDD, but also the same.
On a physical machine everything works fine.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Try running QEMU with "-M q35" and see if that helps.

Comment: Nothing changed...same problem.